# A320 Avionics Compartment Access Door (Seeking Photo References)

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, airbus-a320, ground-operations, doors

We're software developers currently working on a 3D A320 for training and we're getting quite stuck finding any suitable references of the Aviation Compartment Access Door - specifically both it's exact location in relation to the Access Panel, as well as its operation (what needs to be pushed/pulled/twisted etc. and in what order).

Online we've only managed to find 2 or 3 blurry reference images that are on an A320, and due to Covid we're unable to arrange a site inspection with our usual hosts to capture the details in person (we usually combine photos and 3D scans). Given that our application is for training we want to ensure we replicate it as accurately as its real-world counterpart as possible.

Any reference images, videos and/or descriptions that anyone might be able to share would be really helpful.

Comment: Writing software to train students on something that you're not familiar with & haven't seen in person... not your fault, but still, doesn't exactly inspire confidence in the quality of the final product.

Comment: There are at least 5 access doors to the forward avionics compartment, you need to be more precise (which rack). [This](https://www.scribd.com/document/336827730/Chapter-05) can help (p28) --> 811 and 812 are such doors. Agreeing with @RalphJ, and also that it's not your fault.

Comment: Ralph & @mins absolutely fair assessment - rest assured our subject-matter-expert stakeholders won't be letting anything through until the content is formally validated as accurate, right now we just need enough detail to scope the complexity of the project particularly around the 3D modelling and operation so we can estimate the cost, and while our experts are unable to access aircraft themselves we have to seek community help to get us by. Thank you for your feedback, we'll send your supplied link back to our stakeholders!

Comment: @mins Stakeholders confirmed it's access door 811 that we're looking for photo and/or video references on, thank you for that

Comment: Ok, sorry not being able to provide the answer, one last boost: This [FAA re-publication](https://downloads.regulations.gov/FAA-2020-0328-0004/attachment_6.pdf) states: "*Open the access door 811, refer to AMM Task 52-41-00-010-002*" referring to the task description from the aircraft maintenance manual. The overall view of the area can be found also in this Airbus [firefighting training poster](https://www.airbus.com/content/dam/corporate-topics/publications/backgrounders/techdata/aircraft-rescue-and-firefighting-charts/Airbus-Commercial-Aircraft-ARFC-A320.pdf).